# Updates to my ViewModel are not causing a recomposition

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

Apologies for the N00b level here, but I am running into an issue with my sample app... At its basic level, I have a product listing page, that uses Retrofit to get data from my server. I want to allow for refreshing the product data via a button click (later, a gesture). I can see that my server I getting hit, but I cannot get the status to update while the refresh is happening...

Here's my composable:

```
fun Shop() {
  val productViewModel: ProductViewModel = viewModel()

  Column() {
    val productUiState = productViewModel.productUiState

    // Following shows "loading" then "done" on initial component load, 
    // but does NOT go back through that cycle when I click the Reload button
    Text(productUiState.status)

    when (productUiState.status) {
        "loading" -> LoadingImage()
        "done" -> Text(productUiState.products?.size.toString())
    }

    Button(onClick = { productViewModel.getProducts() }) {
        Text("Reload")
    }
}
```

And my ViewModel:

```kt
    data class ProductUiState(
       var status: String,
       var products: List<Product>?
    )

    class ProductViewModel : ViewModel() {
       var productUiState: ProductUiState by mutableStateOf(
          ProductUiState(
            status = "loading",
            products = null
          )
       )

       init {
          getProducts()
       }

       fun getProducts() {
          // The following doesn't seem to do anything when I click Reload in my Composable...
          productUiState.status = "loading"
          // Whereas this does fetch new data when made available by the server, and my Composable shows that new data
          viewModelScope.launch {
              productUiState = try {
                val listResult = POSApi.retrofitService.getProducts()
                ProductUiState("done", listResult)
              } catch (e: IOException) {
                ProductUiState("error", listOf())
              }
          }
       }
    }
```